# How to delete variable which can be pointer (template)?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, memory-management

```
template<class I>
class list_node {
public:
    I val;
    list_node(list_node<I>* p, list_node<I>* n, I value) :prev(p), next(n), val(value) {};
    list_node(I value) :list_node(NULL, NULL, value) {};
    list_node<I>* next;
    list_node<I>* prev;
    ~list_node() { if (std::is_pointer<I>::value) { delete I; } }
};
```

I have a class like this. Users can pass pointer type as the "I" parameter, so I must delete dynamically making an object. But VS 2019 show error that "I can't delete an object that isn't pointers". 
Please, tell me how I can solve this problem. I won't make specializes for this class (except when is any other solutions).

Comment: *Users can pass pointer type as the "I" parameter, so I must delete dynamically making an object.* This is the users responsibility, not yours.  Just like `std::vector<int*>` doesn't call `delete` on the pointers when it is destroyed, neither should your liked list.  If the user of the class wants that, then they should give you an appropriate RAII  type like `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Try with a constexpr-if: `if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<I>) { delete I; }`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If VS is telling you it cannot delete the type that you passed, it is likely because you are passing `I` as an `int` or something like that which is not a pointer.

Comment: In the case of `int a = 5; list_node<int*> (&a);`, `delete`ing such pointer, would invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect example where smart pointers are useful.

If you haven't heard of std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr, now is the time to document yourself on it, they are very useful tools to manage memory safely.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete variable of type `I`. Instead, assume `I` will manage itself, or if it don't, assume the owner (the one newing) will clean it up for you.

Just like `std::vector` won't delete pointers store in it, your container also should not.

I would remove that delete and use `std::unique_ptr` instead:

```
{
    list_node<std::unique_ptr<int>> my_node{new int{3}};
    // ...
} // the new int is deleted here
```